# Site is non-interactive in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

[This](http://www.hwchronicle.com/) site works perfectly fine in chrome, safari, and firefox.

However in IE, the html renders, but nothig is clickable. Non of the anchors work, non of the js works, it's like a rendered text document.

Any idea as to why? I really have no clue why it's not working, there is nothing helpful  in the console log.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

**EDIT:**

Version: IE 11

It seems to be a problem with Edge. When I set IE to version 10 or less, it starts working.

Comment: Have you run the javascript through http://jshint.com ?

Comment: when you say IE, which version of IE do you mean ?

Comment: It works fine with me

Comment: @JohnroePauloCañamaque What version?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it likes this

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
```

from console

```
HTML1513: Extra "<html>" tag found. Only one "<html>" tag should exist per document.
File: www.hwchronicle.com, Line: 8, Column: 1
```

Ie is quite picky about invalid markup